# MSYS how are file permissions defined?

Tags: permissions, msys

I'm super-confused about file permissions in MSYS. Things started to go wrong after my company transferred my windows-user to a different domain. Now I have this concrete problem:

I want to compile cpputest. I unzipped it using windows, started an msys console and owner and group look like this:

```
M.Grunwald@GNA ~/Projects/cpputest-3.8
$ ls -la
total 1956
drwxrwx---+ 1 M.Grunwald Domain Users               0 16. Nov 10:21 .
drwxrwx---+ 1 M.Grunwald COMPANY_DE+Domain Users    0 16. Nov 10:21 ..
-rwxrwx---+ 1 M.Grunwald Domain Users           11030  2. Mai 2016  .cproject
-rwxrwx---+ 1 M.Grunwald Domain Users             228  2. Mai 2016  .gitattributes
-rwxrwx---+ 1 M.Grunwald Domain Users             746 25. Mai 12:32 .gitignore

and so on.
```

When I start autogen.sh, this happens:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
autom4te-2.69: cannot open autom4te.cache/requests: Permission denied

$ ls -lad autom4te.cache/
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 M.Grunwald Domain Users 0 Nov 16 10:23 autom4te.cache/
```

So the directory belongs to me, I have all permissions, but I'm not allowed to touch anything in it:

```
$ touch autom4te.cache/requests
touch: cannot touch 'autom4te.cache/requests': Permission denied
```

It seems that "I" am not really M.Grunwald and don't belong to "Domain Users", neither... On the other hand:

```
$ echo "UID: $UID  GID: $GROUPS"
UID: 1117609  GID: 1049089

$ ls -lnad autom4te.cache/
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 1117609 1049089 0 Nov 16 10:23 autom4te.cache/
```

So the IDs match. umask is 0000, too and still group and others don't have write permission. If I want to change this:

```
$ chmod g+w autom4te.cache
chmod: changing permissions of 'autom4te.cache': Permission denied
```

Now I'm completely confused and blocked on many similar tasks (always permission problems, cpputest is just one example). Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after I re-ran the mingw installer.